# Signing in with AWS amplify on React Native

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I'm unable to get AWS Amplify to authenticate to my AWS Cognito setup. I use the following code to set up.

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        IdentityPoolId: 'us-west-2:XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX',
        region: 'us-west-2',
        UserPoolId: 'us-west-2_XXXXXXXX',
        ClientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

    }
});
```

and this code to sign in

```
Auth.signIn(this.state.username, this.state.password)
.then(user => console.log(user))
.catch(err => console.log(err)); //"No userPool" logged here
```

However I get the error **No userPool** logged as an error.

The example here: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/media/authentication_guide.md has some of the configuration attributes starting with a lower case, however when I follow that I get the Red Screen.

Answer (score 5):

It is just wrong config. The example in guide is:

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab', //REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X', // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234', //OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolWebClientId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234', //OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried the first time, with lower case attributes, however I get the React-Native Red Screen with the error *Both UserPoolId and ClientId are required*. 

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
  identityPoolId: 'us-west-2:XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX', //REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        region: 'us-west-2', // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        userPoolId: 'us-west-2_XXXXXXXX', //OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
    }
});

Comment: Right. userPoolId and userPoolWebClientId are required for signIn / signUp / signOut etc. Guide should be more clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out going through the AWS code, the userPoolWebClientId was required, and as Richard Zhang pointed out above I was using the wrong attributes.